# checking for minimum between two array.shape elements and finding out where it came from

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of any shape, at one point my code is the following:

```
if a.shape[-1]!=b.shape[-1]:
            if max(a.shape[-1],b.shape[-1])%min(a.shape[-1],b.shape[-1])==0:
```

I want to know how to find out where the minimum and the maximum belongs to, because I will need to do something with the array that got minimum. Did the minimum belong to array `a` or `b`?

Comment: why use `min` and `max` with two numbers just an `if a.shape[-1]  > b.shape[-1]: esle:` is sufficient

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat yeah I guess.. I still have to nest `if a.shape[-1] % b.shape[-1]==0` inside that but I guess it's probably the shortest way anyways